# Deadlock while processing resultset

Tags: java, collections, deadlock

I am processing around 300k records fetched in a resultset.

```
ResultSetMetaData md = resultSet.getMetaData();
List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String prodIda2a2 = "";
        String skuIda2a2 = "";
        String pslIda2a2 = "";
        String sslIda2a2 = "";
        String csIda2a2 = "";
        int dataColumns = md.getColumnCount();
        Map<String, String> row = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= dataColumns; ++i) {
            String columnName = md.getColumnName(i);
            String value = String.valueOf(resultSet.getObject(i));
            if (columnName.equals("productidA2A2"))
                prodIda2a2 = value;
            else if (columnName.equals("skuidA2A2"))
                skuIda2a2 = value;
            else if (columnName.equals("productseasonlinkidA2A2"))
                pslIda2a2 = value;
            else if (columnName.equals("skuseasonlinkidA2A2"))
                sslIda2a2 = value;
            else if (columnName.equals("skucostsheetidA2A2"))
                csIda2a2 = value;

            row.put(columnName, value);
        }
        list.add(row);
```

I am getting deadlock in the following two lines.

```
String value = String.valueOf(resultSet.getObject(i));
row.put(columnName, value);
```

I would appreciate any help. Following is the exception:

> "RMI TCP Connection(8)-10.13.16.6" Id=30 daemon prio=5 RUNNABLE
>         Blocked (cnt): 400; Waited (cnt): 391
>         CPU nanos: 40859375000; User nanos: 39515625000; Bytes allocated: 23685333312
>         Method context: q3ixzpr;k5d8myjr;13996;h2ex9v;1; DB session: 72
>         % of 1 CPU used by context: 10.185872840911994 (40859375000/401137689800); Bytes allocated by context: 23684723280
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1019)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
>   at com.integration.common.initialload.loader.pushData(Loader.java:255)
>   at
>   com.integration.common.initialload.loader.initloader(Loader.java:71)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at
>   wt.method.MethodResultWriter.writeExternal(MethodResultWriter.java:165)
>   at wt.method.MethodResult.writeExternal(MethodResult.java:226)   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1456)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) 
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:290)   at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:367)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
>   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$46/1748043306.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Locked synchronizers:
>       - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@5c5239fa

Comment: Please show the error

Comment: Why do you believe you have a deadlock?

Comment: Updated the original post with exception.

Comment: Why you init Map<String, String> row = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>(); in cycle? Its always new!

Comment: Are there other threads involved? It makes no sense to combine a `ConcurrentHashMap` with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Besides that, for a deadlock, you need at least two threads and since the thread’s state is `RUNNABLE` it doesn’t look like a deadlock. Instead, I’d check whether you have enough memory…

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was a memory issue.